# How can I decrypt JWE token in Blazor WASM?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, blazor-webassembly

This is my code that generates a JWE token in ASP.NET Core:

```
    var secretKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("LongerThan-16Char-SecretKey");
    var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(secretKey), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

    var encryptionkey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("16CharEncryptKey");
    var encryptingCredentials = new EncryptingCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(encryptionkey), SecurityAlgorithms.Aes128KW,      SecurityAlgorithms.Aes128CbcHmacSha256);


    var claims = await _getClaimsAsync(user);

    var descriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Issuer = "MyWebsite",
        Audience = "MyWebsite",
        IssuedAt = DateTime.Now,
        NotBefore = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(0),
        Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60),
        SigningCredentials = signingCredentials,
        EncryptingCredentials = encryptingCredentials,
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims)
    };

    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    var securityToken = tokenHandler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(descriptor);


    var refreshToken = await _unitOfWork.UserRefreshTokenRepository.CreateToken(user.Id);
    await _unitOfWork.CommitAsync();

    return new AccessToken(securityToken,refreshToken.ToString());
```

I want to use this token in Blazor Web Assembly. This is my code to read the JWT token. But it doesn't work:

```
  private IEnumerable<Claim> ParseTokenClaims(string access_token)
    {
      
        return Jose.JWT.Payload<Dictionary<string, object>>(access_token)
            .Select(keyValue => new Claim(keyValue.Key, keyValue.Value.ToString() ?? string.Empty))
            .ToArray();
    }
```

I need to decrypt this token, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

install `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` Package,

Then change your method like:

```
private Dictionary<object, object> ParseTokenClaims(string access_token)
    {

        var jwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ReadJwtToken(access_token);

        var claims = jwt.Claims.ToList();

        Dictionary<object, object> result = new Dictionary<object, object>();
        foreach (var claim in claims)
        {
            result.Add(claim.ToString().Trim().Split(":")[0], claim.ToString().Trim().Split(":")[1]);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Now the claims in payload can be inserted into dictionary.

[image]

Comment: it not work , because we need to decrypt token with secrecKey but you did not use.

Comment: But the secret key is just to verify if the JWT is modified. In your question, I think you just want to get payload from jwt.

Comment: yes, i need pay load